# Android - java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class : no empty constructor

Tags: java, android, exception, runtime-error, instantiation

I am making an app that displays a speed dial but whenever I run the app, I get the message

> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class : no empty constructor

How do I fix this?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Needle extends View {

private Paint linePaint;
private Path linePath;
private Paint needleScrewPaint;

private Matrix matrix;
private int framePerSeconds = 100;
private long animationDuration = 10000;
private long startTime;

public Needle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.postInvalidate();
    init();
}

public Needle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.postInvalidate();
    init();
}

public Needle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.postInvalidate();
    init();
}

private void init(){

    linePaint = new Paint();
    linePaint.setColor(Color.RED); // Set the color
    linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); // set the border and fills the inside of needle
    linePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f); // width of the border
    linePaint.setShadowLayer(8.0f, 0.1f, 0.1f, Color.GRAY); // Shadow of the needle

    linePath = new Path();
    linePath.moveTo(50.0f, 50.0f);
    linePath.lineTo(130.0f, 40.0f);
    linePath.lineTo(600.0f, 50.0f);
    linePath.lineTo(130.0f, 60.0f);
    linePath.lineTo(50.0f, 50.0f);
    linePath.addCircle(130.0f, 50.0f, 20.0f, Path.Direction.CW);
    linePath.close();

    needleScrewPaint = new Paint();
    needleScrewPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    needleScrewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    needleScrewPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(130.0f, 50.0f, 10.0f,
            Color.DKGRAY, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    matrix.postRotate(1.0f, 130.0f, 50.0f); // rotate 10 degree every second
    canvas.concat(matrix);

    canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(130.0f, 50.0f, 16.0f, needleScrewPaint);

    if(elapsedTime < animationDuration){
        this.postInvalidateDelayed(10000 / framePerSeconds);
    }

    //this.postInvalidateOnAnimation();
    invalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the class Needle ?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Strack trace, let the dog see the rabbit

Comment: @MicheleLacorte Needle is the only class, its the main activity

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean "stack trace"? Im sorry i just started using Stack Overflow today

Comment: "What do you mean "stack trace"?" -- I mean the Java stack trace, showing where your exception came from. See [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/115145) to learn what a Java stack trace is. See [this Stack Oveflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174/115145) to learn how to get it from Android Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: "Needle is the only class, its the main activity" -- no, it is not. `public class Needle extends View`. It is not a subclass of `Activity`. It is a subclass of `View`.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward- you need an empty constructor. `Needle(){....}`

Comment: @DanielM. I've tried this but it hasnt worked

Comment: @DanielM. I get this message "There is no default constructor available in android.view.View"

Comment: @CommonsWare     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{needle.ibizsmart.com.needle/com.needle.views.Needle}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.needle.views.Needle; no empty constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{needle.ibizsmart.com.needle/com.needle.views.Needle}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.needle.views.Needle; no empty constructor
```

Somewhere in your manifest, you have an `<activity>` element that indicates that `com.needle.views.Needle` is a subclass of `Activity`.

And, somewhere in your Java code, you are calling `startActivity()`, with an `Intent` that points to `com.needle.views.Needle`.

However, `com.needle.views.Needle` does not inherit from `Activity`. It inherits from `View`. You cannot use it as an activity.

You are certainly welcome to create a different class that *does* inherit from `Activity`, that uses `Needle` as part of its user interface.